# How to efficiently implement bitwise rotate of an arbitrary sequence?

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

"The permutation p of n elements defined by an index permutation p(i) = (i + k) mod n is called the k-*rotation*." -- [Stepanov & McJones](http://elementsofprogramming.com/)

`std::rotate` has become a well known algorithm thanks to [Sean Parent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2tWOdzgXHA&t=12s), but how to efficiently implement it for an arbitrary sequence of bits?
By efficient, I mean minimizes at least two things, i) the number of writes and ii) the worst-case space complexity.

That is, the input should be similar to `std::rotate` but bit-wise specific, I guess like this:

1. A pointer to the memory where the bit sequence starts.
2. Three bit indices: `first`, `middle` and `last`.

The type of the pointer could be any unsigned integer, and presumably the larger the better. (Boost.Dynamic Bitset calls it the "block".)

It's important to note that the indices may all be offset from the start of a block by different amounts.

According to Stepanov and McJones, rotate on random access data can be implemented in n + gcd(n, k) assignments. The algorithm that reverses each subrange followed by reversing the entire range takes 3n assignments. (However, I agree with the comments below that it is effectively 2n assignments.) Since the bits in an array can be accessed randomly, I assume the same optimal bound applies. Each assignment will usually require two reads because of different subrange block offsets but I'm less concerned about reads than writes.

Does an efficient or optimal implementation of this algorithm already exist out in the open source wild?
If not, how would one do it?

I've looked through Hacker's Delight and Volume 4A of Knuth but can't find an algorithm for it.

Comment: the algorithm does exist, it is `std::rotate` you just need the right container/iterators

Comment: @user463035818 how can that avoid writing the bits one by one?

Comment: what do you mean by "avoid writing the bits one by one" ? How else do you rotate bits?

Comment: By writing the appropriate bytes/words.

Comment: but before you know what byte to write you need to read and write bits, no?

Comment: only for shifts that are multiple of 8 you can rotate bytes, but in that case why shift bits in the first place?

Comment: Clearly the bytes have to be recombined in some way. That is not the same thing as writing bits one by one.

Comment: @harold you are the bit-manipulation master :P I have to admit, I have no idea how to do it and I'd love to see an elegant solution

Answer (score 2):

Using a `vector<uint32_t>`, for example, it's easy and reasonably efficient to do the fractional-element part of the rotation in one pass yourself (shift_amount%32), and then call `std::rotate` to do the rest.   The fractional part is easy and only operates on adjacent elements, except at the ends, so you only need to remember one partial element while you're working.

If you want to do the whole thing yourself, then you can do the rotation by reversing the order of the entire vector, and then reversing the order of the front and back sections.  The trick to doing this efficiently is that when you reverse the whole vector, you don't actually bit-reverse each element -- you just *think* of them as being in the opposite order.  The reversal of the front and back sections is trickier and requires you to remember 4 partial elements while you work.

In terms of writes to memory or cache, both of the above methods make *2N* writes.  The optimal rotation you refer to in the question takes *N*, but if you extend it to work with fractional-word rotations, then each write spans two words and it then takes *2N* writes.  It provides no advantage and I think it would turn out to be complicated.

That said... I'm sure you could get closer to *N* writes with a fixed amount of register storage by doing *m* words at a time, but that's a lot of code for a simple rotation, though, and your time (or at least *my time* :) would be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. My concern with both is that although they might be simple in terms of implementation, they are not efficient in terms of assignments. I'll put some more theory in the question to explain.

Comment: @JeremyW.Murphy: Real-world efficiencies are different from theoretical efficiencies. You aim to minimize the number of writes, but that fails to distinguish between register writes, L1 cache writes, L2 cache writes and main memory writes. Matt's algorithm can keep the fractional part in a register, and the adjacent writes will go to L1 cache.

Comment: @JeremyW.Murphy I put in a note about memory efficiency

Comment: Yup, I agree that a practically optimal algorithm can be quite different to a theoretically optimal one, but I want to keep the question relatively straightforward.

Comment: I think I need more detail to be convinced the first idea--shift then `std::rotate`--actually works.
Let's say the indices modulo block size for `f`, `m` and `l` are 1, 2 and 5 respectively.
After rotation, the first subrange has been right-shifted by 5 - 2 = 3 relative to the block whereas the second subrange has been left-shifted by 2 - 1 = 1 relative to the block. Those shifts cannot be done in-place (prior to `std::rotate`) as they would cause overlap at `m`. Maybe I have misunderstood your idea, so more detail would be appreciated.

Comment: And yeah, although the triple reverse in-place algorithm is theoretically 3n assignments, it's only 2n assignments in practice.

Comment: @JeremyW.Murphy I left out details in both descriptions, since they don't affect the performance question.  Using std::rotate may require you to pre-shift the two parts of the array by different amounts, and fix up some words at the boundaries.